# Dynamic table Javascript - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I m trying to access to some information in a table by HTML and **it is working**, but I would like to do it after clicking a button and not `onInit`, so I guess that I need to do it by `Javascript`or `Typescript`

It would be perfect to create the table by HTML but filling it by `Javascript` or `Typescript` after clicking the button.

The table is the following:
**HTML**

```
<table id="myTableSystems" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th>{{ 'Checkbox' | translate }}</th>
      <th>{{ 'MappingMult' | translate }}</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let receiver of testCase.receivers;" class="pointer">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>{{receiver.mappingMult}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what info do u need to access after click

Comment: where is the code for `button`

Comment: your code is commented - uncomment it

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to render the table on user action instead of rendering it through component life-cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component.ts file you will need to create a function to fill the object "testCase".

I'm not sure how the component is getting/receiving the data for "testCase". You will need to refactor the logic so that you get the data for "testCase" in the fillData function.

component.ts

```
  public fillData(): void {
    this.testCase.receivers = [{mappingMult: 'data'}];
  }
```

component.html

```
<button type="button" (click)="fillData()" class="">Click To Fill Data</button>

<table *ngIf="testCase" id="myTableSystems" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
  <thead>
    <th>{{ 'Checkbox' | translate }}</th>
    <th>{{ 'MappingMult' | translate }}</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let receiver of testCase.receivers;" class="pointer">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>{{receiver.mappingMult}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I totally forgot the *ngIf for the table. Thanks